# Jquery Problem in IE

Tags: jquery, html

Some has helped me with my last question, for which I'm very thankful. Unfortunately, I keep running into series of weird problems on Internet Explorer.

Here's my code and when you click on the `Family` list item, it's background extends to the children.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#flip_1").click(function() {
                    $("#panel_1").slideToggle("slow");
                }); 
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .navigation ul {
                font-size: 12px;
                list-style-type: none;

                padding: 0; 
                margin: 0; 
            }


            .navigation {
                float: left;
                width: 200px;
            }

            .navigation li {
                background-color: #F5F2EE;
                background-position: left top;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                border: 1px solid #E9E3DD;
                height: auto;
                margin-bottom: 4px;
                padding: 4px 5px 4px 20px;
            }

            .navigation li:hover {
                background-color: #DEB887;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .nodisplay {
                display:none; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Second</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Other Things</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Process</a></li>

                <li id="flip_1">
                    <span>Family</span>
                </li>

                <div id="panel_1" class="nodisplay">
                    <ul>
                        <li> First</li>
                        <li> Second</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <li>More</li>
            </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway that the children `li`s under `family` can appear like other items and not like they are being surrounded by the `family` background color? This weird behavior only happens in Compatibility View inside Internet Explorer.

Comment: Before I edited it, your code was an absolute mess. Also, does anyone know if `{ padding: 0; margin: 0; }` on it's own is valid CSS, seeing as it doesn't have a selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this happens in other browsers for me as well. You need to change the .navigation li selector to a .navigation>li selector if you want it to affect only immediate children, and not all descendants. I think that's what you're asking for?

Comment: Alternately, if you want a third background color, you could add a .navigation li li selector.

Comment: Do note that the child selector `>` doesn't work in IE7, even though QuirksMode says it does.